# Выпадающий список

Tags: android, java

**ОБНОВЛЕНО 22.09.2012**

Здравствуйте, возник такой вопрос:  я хочу сделать в ActionBar выпадающий список, но таким образом, чтобы в закрытом состоянии было написан login и он при выборе не заменялся, т.е.

> `Закрытый вид :
> login 
> Открытый вид : 
> login
>     a) Настройки
>     б) О программе.`

Т.е. login должен быть как бы титулом списка и не являться его элементом.Например, программа evernote. Там титулом является ваша учетная запись нажимая на нее открывается список : "Об аккаунте, Настройки, Выйти из системы" Как такое сделать. Вот я например делаю так, но у меня login тоже входит в список.

```
   String[] actions = new String[] {
            "login",
            "Настройки",
            "О приложении",
            "Выйти из приложения"
        };
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, actions);

        /** Enabling dropdown list navigation for the action bar */
        getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

        /** Defining Navigation listener */
        ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {

            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(dataAdapter, new OnNavigationListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });

ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[] {
            getString(R.string.title_section1),
            getString(R.string.title_section2),
            getString(R.string.title_section3),
        }));
```

Comment: Ругается на строчку :
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {
 и на строчку :
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(dataAdapter, new OnNavigationListener() {

Comment: Удали implements ....

Comment: теперь ругается только на строчку 
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(dataAdapter, new OnNavigationListener() {

Comment: Логи выкладывай, не на битве экстрасенсов же)))

Comment: Я свой кусок писал в проектет и он рабочий. А ты спируй лог ошибки и сюда вставь текстом. Может у тебя ипморт плохой, в обнови импорт, в еклипсе это быстрыекнопки ctrl + shift( или alt) + O

Answer (score 1):

А чо к `ArrayAdapter`'у прикрутить слушателя (`ArrayAdapter.setOnClickListener`) и по нажатию стартануть `Activity` - низзя?